# Where is Fuseki server storing triple data?

Tags: python, jena, semantic-web, fuseki

I have installed Jena Fuseki on my computer and I after I create dataset I see in my file system that it appears under `fuseki\run\configuration` folder, but I cannot find the triples that I upload to this dataset.

I want to process datasets with Python and then store them in jena fuseki, so I don't want to use the web app GUI that jena provides for uploading new triples. My question is how to accomplish this and where does Jena store uploaded triples?

Comment: If you created a persistent database via the UI, it's in run/db/<NAME>. If the database is in a configuration file on server startup, it is whereever the config puts it. Things are not stores as RDF file - they are triplestore database (TDB by default).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the web app UI, Fuseki offers a number of ways to get data into it:

- [The `soh` set of command line tools, in particular `s-put`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/soh.html). These commands can be called from Python.
- [The SPARQL Graph Store Protocol](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-http-rdf-update/). This is a simple HTTP protocol.
- [SPARQL Update](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-update-20130321/) over the [SPARQL Protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/). There are Python client libraries for the SPARQL Protocol, see for example [here](https://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160437/insert-delete-update-query-using-sparqlwrapper).

It sounds like you are trying to upload data by directly accessing Fuseki's internal file storage. That's probably not a good idea. Access should go through the officially supported interfaces.